# Does Cloned VM use the same Hard Disk space of Guest?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization, redhat, linux-networking

if i clone a guest VM in RHEL6 does the clone use the same Hard disk space of the guest?

The aim is not to, as each guest VM, cloned or the normal guest should have it own hard disk space allocated.

And it would have been easier if the clones really use their own space as i need to make 16 VM's, each with its own Harddisk space and same RAM size allocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A clone is an exact *copy*, so no, they shouldn't use the same space. What would be the point in this?

Comment: So i can make 1 VM running and clone it to make the required amount(my case 16) of guest VM's which has the same size of HardDisk and RAM allocation. Bcoz i was earlier thinking of making each VM individually.So cloning saves time.

Comment: Depending on the guest OS and how the VMs are configured, it could work that way. But you have to consider things like IP addresses etc., that have to be configured individually for every machine.

Comment: Ok, Thanks a lot,I got it and all set to clone 16.